# Typescript React Passing parameter to setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am a beginner and I am doing this...

```
<i className="fa fa-trash-alt" onClick={() => this.handleDelete("trippurpose")} />
```

My handle delete is written like this...

```
handleDelete(whichitem: string) {
    // this handles someone changing an input text field
    console.log(whichitem);

    if (whichitem === "trippurpose") {
      this.setState({
        trippurpose: "",
      });
    } else if (whichitem === "projecttask") {
      this.setState({
        projecttask: "",
      });
    }
  }
```

What's I'd prefer to do is...

```
  handleDelete(whichitem: string) {
    // this handles someone changing an input text field

      this.setState({
        [whichitem]: "",
      });
  
    }
```

But when I do that I get an error...
Argument of type `{[x: string]: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TemplatePopoverState | ((prevState: Readonly, props... and much more...

From reading up it seems that doing the [whichitem].

```
      this.setState({
        [whichitem]: "",
      });
```

Is the correct way to go but I suspect it's something in the method parameters that is wrong - any hints? As I said I am a complete novice..The ultimate goal is to call a function that pass a string that reflects the value of the input text field I want to clear (set to "").

Comment: Please share whole example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While setting dynamic value to setState, you need to specify the key to be one among the state keys, you can write the above funcition like

```
handleDelete(whichitem: keyof TemplatePopoverState) {
    // this handles someone changing an input text field

      this.setState({
        [whichitem]: "",
      } as Pick<TemplatePopoverState, keyof TemplatePopoverState>);
  
    }
```

For more reference refer [**this github issue**](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/26635).

Comment: I had to make a small addition...adding as unknown (which someone mentioned in that github link). That's well above my knowledge base so THANK YOU.
```
 handleDelete(whichitem: keyof TemplatePopoverState) {
    // this handles someone changing an input text field
    console.log(whichitem);
    this.setState(({
      [whichitem]: "",
    } as unknown) as Pick<TemplatePopoverState, keyof TemplatePopoverState>);
  }
```